# Sending e-mails only to verified addresses

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email

Is there a way to implement automatic verification of e-mail addresses in Outlook?

What I would like to achieve is

- users can send e-mails only to addresses which are in address book or on some LDAP directory
- if any of the e-mails are not in those directories e-mail is held until user either removes unregistered recipient or registers such recipient

If the above is not possible are there some other suggestions that would make sending e-mails to a wrong address less likely.

Comment: POP3? Exchange? etc? And you refer to *users*, so how many people/accounts/computers are you looking at? If you've lots of users to cover this would probably be a better fit over at Server Fault...

Comment: This relates to sending from Outlook; I am checking if there are client side options to take care of this. (we do have Exchange at one location)

Answer (score 0):

This can be generally (client independently and centrally) configured on MTA. If you have an access to the SMTP gateway settings, you can add LDAP based routers and do exactly what you need. Do you use exchange for the gateway?